# OpenStack training-labs - VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid machine group

Tags: windows, virtualbox, openstack

I am trying to install OpenStack instance into VirtualBox VMs as on https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Documentation/training-labs#Building_the_cluster

after `./osbash.sh -w cluster` I get error

> VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid machine group 'C:/Program Files/Git/labs'

Yes, `C:/Program Files/Git` is location of git-bash.exe that is actual Git-Windows Bash, but **how to make `osbash.sh` proceed with correct machine group name?**

The scripts are stable Mitaka from http://docs.openstack.org/training_labs/ for Windows
http://tarballs.openstack.org/training-labs/dist/labs-stable-mitaka.zip

```
Paul@aspire MINGW64 /d/Workspaces/OpenStack/labs-stable-mitaka/labs/osbash
$ ./osbash.sh -b cluster
Base disk: base-ssh-mitaka-ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64
Distribution name:  ubuntu
Virtualization provider: virtualbox
Creating Windows batch scripts: no
Creating cluster on this machine: yes
VM access method: ssh
GUI type: headless
 2016年09月20日 18:09:36 osbash starting
Creating basedisk.
2016年09月20日 18:09:36 osbash vm_install starts.
Asked to delete VM "base" (not found)
Creating VM "base"
VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid machine group 'C:/Program Files/Git/labs'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "ComposeMachineFilename(bstrName.raw(), bstrPrimaryGroup.raw(), createFlags.raw(), bstrBaseFolder.raw(), bstrSettingsFile.asOutParam())" at line 264 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
FAILURE: VBoxManage: createvm --name base --register --ostype Ubuntu_64 --groups /labs
```

P.S. The same error when trying the latest master from `git://git.openstack.org/openstack/training-labs.git`

Raised bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/labs/+bug/1625562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation may have mislead you. You don't need a POSIX environment to build the cluster on Windows and (as you found out) using the bash scripts does not work on Windows.

All you need is a VirtualBox installation and the content of the zip file you downloaded. There is no need to add VBoxManage to the Path, the scripts should find the executable anyway.

The zip file you downloaded contains the Windows batch files that build the cluster on Windows in the wbatch directory. Just double-click them: 1) create_hostnet 2) create_base 3) create_ubuntu_cluster_node

That's all. The scripts will set up the VMs, download the Ubuntu ISO image and build the OpenStack cluster.